# Пагинация PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo, pagination, пагинация

Помогите переделать пагинацию под себя.
Работаю через АПИ получаю 
номер страницы - 1, элементы - 20000, всего страниц - 1000.
То есть 
`Page: <?php echo $trend->page ?> Items: <?php echo $trend->total_results ?>  TotalP: <?php echo $trend->total_pages ?>` Пагинация работает только так

````
<?php
$limit = 5;
for ($i=1; $i <= $trend->total_pages ; $i++) { 
  echo "<a href='?page=$i'> $i </a>";
}
?>
Но выдаёт 1000 страниц даже лимит не работает



Сам код пагинации как его переделать под себя?

if ($_GET['page']) {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
  $page = 1;
}
$limit = 3;
$number = ($limit * $page) - $limit;
$num_rows = $db->query('select count(*) from users')->fetchColumn(); 
$str_page = ceil($num_rows/$limit);
$sql = "SELECT * from users LIMIT $number, $limit";
foreach ($db->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  echo $row;
};
for ($i=1; $i <= $str_page ; $i++) { 
  echo "<a href='?page=$i'> $i </a>";
}```
````

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Не могу поменять значения во втором варианте на свои не работает лимит и все остальное, выдает по 1000 страниц как есть когда ставлю тотал пэйдж

Comment: Ничего не понял. при чем здесмь ПДО если работа через АПИ?

Comment: Вопрос решен с помощью simplePagination.js